# Check if string is alphabetic and does not contain some specific words

Tags: javascript, regex

I use `/^[a-zA-Z]+$/` to check if a string is alphabetic and `/^((?!some|words|in|blacklist).)*$/` to validate if it does not contain some specific words.

How can I check for both conditions in a single regex pattern?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
/^(?!some|words|in|blacklist)[a-zA-Z]+$/
```